# What phase to use if I want the goal (antrun:run) to be run after creating exploded war?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

I have some ant task in my .pom, which copies exploded .war to the server. I want it to be run after creation of exploded .war. What should I enter in plugin configuration in `<phase>` part?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) link for all the Maven life cycle phases.  You should find what you're looking for about 3/4 down the page.

If your deploying the exploded ware for testing locally, then the phase you want is probably going to be pre-integration-test.